# Lodash chaining with sortBy produces error while vanilla sort works

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Given this:

```
let nums = [1,5,4]
let sorter = (a,b) => a.property > b.property ? 1 : -1;
let mapper = x => {return {property:x}}
```

This throws an error:

```
_.chain(nums).map(mapper).sortBy(sorter).value()
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
```

While this does not:

```
nums.map(mapper).sort(sorter)
// [{"property":1},{"property":4},{"property":5}]
```

What gives?  Are we not guaranteed that `sortBy` will run after `map`?  Or am I missing something truly obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lodash's `sortBy` function accepts as a second argument the iteratees to sort by, and doesn't accept the same pattern of sort function that the native `sort()` function does.  You can just place in the string of the key you want to sort on:

```
_.chain(nums).map(mapper).sortBy('property').value()
```

Or pass in a function that points to the property you want to sort on:

```
_.chain(nums).map(mapper).sortBy((o) => o.property).value()
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorter function that lodash takes only has one parameter:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

https://jsfiddle.net/jq26573q/

```
let sorter = (o) => o.property;
```

Although even better is to specify the attribute directly:

```
let sorter = 'property';
```